# Json webtoken dependency will not resolve in pom.xml

Tags: java, spring, maven

I am currently working on a Spring Project, which I am new to, and have no idea why this dependency I got from the maven repository will now resolve itself. I have tried to use both the separated dependency (jjwt-api, etc..) and the one pasted in my pom.xml below but it will not resolve. If anyone can help me figure this out that would great appreciated.

Spring v2.6.4
Java JDK 17
Error message: Dependency 'com.auth0:java-jwt:3.18.3' not found

```
l version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.4</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.legacy-banking</groupId>
    <artifactId>legacyBankingAPI</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>legacyBankingAPI</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-oauth2-client</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
 ---------THIS IS THE DEPENDENCY IN QUESTION BELOW---------------------------
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.auth0</groupId>
            <artifactId>java-jwt</artifactId>
            <version>3.18.3</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Comment: What do you mean it won't resolve? Can you post what you have tried and what your error message is?

Comment: @mikeb my apologize. See above "Error Message". Basically i cannot find the dependency. I tried another set of dependency from a tutorial before trying the one in the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [MvnRepository](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.auth0/java-jwt/3.18.3) page says, it's in the central repo, and the central repo link to the pom.xml of the dependency also works: https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/auth0/java-jwt/3.18.3/java-jwt-3.18.3.pom

So did you maybe try to resolve it once when you were offline? Failed resolving also is cached in your local maven repo, so you might have to clean that up. You can try to use

```
mvn dependency:get -Dartifact=com.auth0:java-jwt:3.18.3
```

or you clean the cached "missing" dependency manually: go to your local maven repo (usually in *~/.m2/repository*), descend to *com/auth0/java-jwt* and remove the folder *3.18.3* inside, then run your maven build again.

Comment: Thats what it was. I have been adding only spring dependencies and not any external dependencies so when I put them in I was not getting "Dependency not found", so I did not know I would have to rebuild the structure again to resolve an issue like that. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I just reloaded the pom.xml file and it the works.